# What is the function of the word "that" here? (And is "absent" a verb in this sentence?)

Tags: verbs, prepositions, that

What is the grammatical function of "that" in the following sentence. I'm having a hard time explaining to students why a verb (absent) is preceded by "that." Students assume a noun should follow "that." Any ideas??

Ex) "It is clear to me," she said, " **that absent this kind of social media interaction**, there are things students think about that normally they'd never say."

Comment: 'Absent' here is a preposition, not a verb. Synonym 'without'. See eg [R H K Webster's; AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absent): it is informative that Collins does not include this intercategorial polyseme.

Comment: The question is unclear. The title asks about the function of *absent*. The body asks about the function of *that*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your comment's completely correct. But your new title is not what the OP is actually interested in, it seems from the comment under my answer post (and his original question).

Answer (score 1):

> "It is clear to me," she said, " **that absent this kind of social media interaction**, there are things students think about that normally they'd never say."

**That**

The word *that* is a subordinator here. It introduces the content clause:

- that [absent this kind of social media interaction, there are things students think about that normally they'd never say]

This clause is functioning as a Complement of the verb *BE* (technically, it is what we call an Extraposed Subject). It tells us about what exactly is clear to the speaker.

It is the same *that* which we find in the sentence:

- It is clear that you're going to pass the exam.

Or:

- I think that you're very clever.

It is *NOT* the determiner *that*, which we find in sentences like:

- Give me that book,

---

**Absent**

The word *absent* means something like *without* or, in this particular instance, *in the absence of*. Technically it is a preposition. Like other prototypical prepositions it takes a noun phrase as a Complement. In this case the noun phrase is *this kind of social media interaction*. The whole preposition phrase is functioning as an Adjunct (read "Adverbial") in the sentence.

We can paraphrase the sentence like this:

> It is clear to me," she said, "that in the absence of this kind of social media interaction, there are things students think about that normally they'd never say.

---

If you scroll a long way down [the linked-to page](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent) at the Merriam Webster dictionary, you will find entry number (3) for *absent*, namely the entry for the preposition:

> **absent**

---

> **preposition** ab·sent \ˈab-sənt\
>
> : in the absence of (something)
>
> **Full Definition of ABSENT**
>
> :  in the absence of :  without
>
> **Examples of ABSENT**
>
> - Absent any objections, the plan will proceed.
> - Absent such an agreement we can go no further.

Comment: Thank you. I read your comment and thought about the various functions of that-clauses used in sentences. This was extremely helpful.

Comment: @Jay - Suggestions: hit the little up-facing triangle to the left of the Answerer's post....  Accept an answer when you're ready.